# PHP strcmp & in_array Not Working

Tags: php, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I am trying to see if an array contains a string, but am having a ton of problems - no matter what I do it always returns false.

Basically I want to see if a stop on the train matches a particular string. I am trying to see if at any point NAME = Ridgewood.

Below is my code that I am using since it is a multi-dimensional array. Array is below code. I've tried `===` `in_array` and even `strcmp` and still get FALSE every time.

```
foreach ($stationResults as $item) {
    $stationStops = $item[STOPS][STOP];

    foreach ($stationStops as $stopitem) {
        $stationName = $stopitem[NAME];
        echo $stationName;
        echo "<br />";
        if ($stationName === "Ridgewood") {
            $stationExists = TRUE;
        }
        else $stationExists = FALSE;
    }

    var_dump($stationExists);
}
```

Here is the array I am searching:

```
[0]=>
  array(18) {
    ["ITEM_INDEX"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["SCHED_DEP_DATE"]=>
    string(19) "12:35:00 07/18/2013"
    ["DESTINATION"]=>
    string(14) "Ridgewood -SEC"
    ["TRACK"]=>
    string(1) "8"
    ["LINE"]=>
    string(4) "BERG"
    ["TRAIN_ID"]=>
    string(4) "1257"
    ["STATUS"]=>
    string(8) "Boarding"
    ["BACKCOLOR"]=>
    string(6) "Silver"
    ["FORECOLOR"]=>
    string(5) "black"
    ["SHADOWCOLOR"]=>
    string(6) "silver"
    ["GPSLATITUDE"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["GPSLONGITUDE"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["GPSTIME"]=>
    string(21) "7/18/2013 12:20:34 PM"
    ["TRAIN_LINE"]=>
    string(18) "Bergen County Line"
    ["STATION_POSITION"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["LINEABBREVIATION"]=>
    string(4) "BERG"
    ["INLINEMSG"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["STOPS"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["STOP"]=>
      array(8) {
        [0]=>
        array(2) {
          ["NAME"]=>
          string(18) "Secaucus Lower Lvl"
          ["TIME"]=>
          string(21) "7/18/2013 12:45:30 PM"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(2) {
          ["NAME"]=>
          string(10) "Rutherford"
          ["TIME"]=>
          string(21) "7/18/2013 12:53:15 PM"
        }
        [2]=>
        array(2) {
          ["NAME"]=>
          string(8) "Garfield"
          ["TIME"]=>
          string(21) "7/18/2013 12:58:30 PM"
        }
        [3]=>
        array(2) {
          ["NAME"]=>
          string(12) "Plauderville"
          ["TIME"]=>
          string(20) "7/18/2013 1:01:15 PM"
        }
        [4]=>
        array(2) {
          ["NAME"]=>
          string(18) "Broadway Fair Lawn"
          ["TIME"]=>
          string(20) "7/18/2013 1:06:00 PM"
        }
        [5]=>
        array(2) {
          ["NAME"]=>
          string(17) "Radburn Fair Lawn"
          ["TIME"]=>
          string(20) "7/18/2013 1:09:15 PM"
        }
        [6]=>
        array(2) {
          ["NAME"]=>
          string(19) "Glen Rock Boro Hall"
          ["TIME"]=>
          string(20) "7/18/2013 1:12:30 PM"
        }
        [7]=>
        array(2) {
          ["NAME"]=>
          string(9) "Ridgewood"
          ["TIME"]=>
          string(20) "7/18/2013 1:16:00 PM"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are `STOPS` and the like actually a constant defined in your code? Or are you using the auto-constant-to-string "feature" of PHP? If so, you probably shouldn't; instead use `"STOPS"`, etc.

Comment: Please, use var_export instead of var_dump.

Comment: @WaleedKhan - I think this was a big issue with the code too, changed this as well.

Comment: @akond why use `var_export` instead of `var_dump`?

Comment: @mattdonders So we can copy and paste your data into the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is broken. You continually reset $stationExists to FALSE every time the loop runs, EXCEPT when you actualy find the station. The code should be

```
$stationExists = false;
foreach(...) {
   if ($stationName == 'Ridgewood') {
      $stationExists = true;
   }
}
```

Consider this sequence:

```
Seacaucus    - no match, $stationExists set to false
Ridgewood    - matched, $stationExists set to TRUE
Plauderville - no match, $stationExists reset to false - oops, now you're stuck
```

So you set stationExists to false outside the loop, and then run the loop.That way it'll only get changed to true if you really find a match, and never reset to false again.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:-

```
function my_search($haystack) {
    $needle = 'value to search for';
    return(strpos($haystack, $needle)); // or stripos() if you want case-insensitive searching.
}

$matches = array_filter($your_array, 'my_search');
```

Btw, there is some flaw in your code. There is no need of this else condition `else $stationExists = FALSE;` inside the loop. Set it as `false` before the loop  runs and if the string matches set it to `true`.

Comment: I've tried in_array and it still returns FALSE for all entries.